# Increase font size in Xcode

Tags: xcode, fonts

How can I increase the font size in Xcode version 3.2.3

When I go to Edit -> Format -> Fonts -> Show Fonts and try to increase the font size, nothing happens.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to go to Xcode > Prefrences > Font and Color and change the font there.

Comment: I don't see anything there that's useful.  It has a setting for the editor font, but how do you increase the font size for the Xcode UI itself?  The default UI font size is unusable - it's tiny, tiny fonts for people who sit about two inches from the screen.

Comment: @JamesMoore Select some or all the type of text and tap the "T" button to bring up the font panel. That's pretty standard Mac UI, I'm assuming you are not familiar with the platform?

Comment: @gcamp, I'm a bit baffled by your comment, but maybe it's exactly what I need.  Virtually all of the UI for Xcode isn't text that can be selected, though.  I'm talking about all the text that Xcode uses outside editors; bring up Xcode, cover the middle third, and look at the text in all the UI elements in the left and right panels.  How would I select any of that?  (The original question was about font size in Xcode, not limited to font size in Xcode editors.  Changing font size in the editor is trivial.)

Comment: Well the original question didn't specify if it was interface font size or editor font size. It was accepted, so I'm assuming this was indeed about editor font size. Changing anything else is fixed, and your only solution is to decrease the resolution of your screen.

Answer (score 16):

top menu bar: XCODE - PREFERENCES - FONTS AND COLORS

choose a style NOT default (i took 'basic')

select one, like PLAIN TEXT, click on the font box, next to the font and size description,
a popup will appear - keep that open

go back to the SOURCE EDITOR tab in FONTS AND COLORS

select all of the options, from PLAIN TEXT DOWN

go back to the popup window, choose your preferred font and size, DOUBLE CLICK ON THE FONT SIZE - all of them will change at once.  or you can do them one by one, your choice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this plugin to change the font size using ⌘ + or ⌘ - :

https://github.com/zats/AdjustFontSize-Xcode-Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Below link 
Hope that will help

[How to increase font size in the Xcode editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339706/how-to-increase-font-size-in-the-xcode-editor)

> 1.Close any projects you have open in Xcode (Otherwise the Font window will be inaccessible while a project is open.)
>
> 2.Go to XCode > Preferences > Fonts & Color
>
> 3.From the 'Theme' box select the theme you want to modify (or select the theme you want to modify and click the "+" button at the bottom of the theme list to clone it first for backup, for there is no undo option)
>
> 4.In the source editor box there is a list of types of text that you may set the font for: Plain text Comments Documentation Comments . . .
>
> 5.Select any or all items from the source editor list and the name and size of the font for that particular text will show up in the 'Font' window below the 'Source Editor' window. (If you happen to skip highlighting one of these, you will be able to get to the Font Inspector and select new sizes, but will wonder why the changes you make are not being applied!)
>
> 6.In the 'Font' window, click the small, almost hidden, and surely poorly design 'T' icon to the right of the font name and size.
>
> 7.Your existing font will be preselected in the font inspector. Whatever changes you make now will be applied to the text types you selected in the 'Source Editor' window. e.g. All Fonts > Menlo > Regular > 16