# Changing text size in xcode version 6.3

Tags: xcode, xcode6

It is very common knowing changing font/text in xcode. I found it difficult for me to do that in version 6.3. Any help please?

Comment: What are you trying to do? And please update to Xcode 6.4.

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to say about Xcode Editor then here it is .

As mention by [**drdiv**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1316384/drdiv) in this post [How to Increase Font Size in the xcode editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339706/how-to-increase-font-size-in-the-xcode-editor/18930077#18930077)

> **Easisest solution:**
>
> 1. Close any open projects.
> 2. *Xcode > Preferences > Font & Colors*
> 3. Make sure to press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all possible text types. Then change the font size from the picker.
>
> [image]
>
> Note:- Of if you want to change the fornt and size of any other like
>   UICONTROL or etc then please explain your question in detail.