# Current line text font size gets increased while typing in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode8

While I am typing on a specific line in workspace, the text present in the particular line's font is getting increased ! And it gets to regular size as soon as I stop typing.

I also upgraded to XCode 8.2 still the same issue occurs.

FYI:
I have also tried the following code to reset the XCode default settings, but still no use.

> defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode

Comment: Are you sure it's the font size and not the view? Could be some sort of accessibility setting on your MAC and nothing to do with XCode?

Comment: Is the error in the app or in the editor? i guess workspace is the editor.

Comment: @atomapps: Yes I am sure its not on the view. Thank you, and the answer has been satisfied and its working fine. Please check the answer for more details.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny: The error is in the editor, It seems some sort of a bug as I described in the answer, please check it out.

Comment: @Bharath looks like second answer is correct one

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Solution:**

[image]

This happens when you change font size for **one** particular element but the other editor's elements are using the previous/default font size.

If you want to change the font size either press `cmd +` or in `preferences -> Fonts and Colors` choose your theme and in the right pane select all the elements (press `cmd a`) and then change the font size.

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1340025/3943054)

Comment: @sayed you saved my day

Comment: wow what a simple but dumb problem. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem but I am not sure is exactly the same. 
Did you try to change this settings?

> Xcode preferences > Fonts & Colors Your chosen theme will have a
>   "current line" option just under the font. Can't remember exactly but
>   I think you can find something there.

Comment: Thank you, there was one item for which the font size is different. After updating it everything is fine, I think even while resetting the Xcode defaults is not resetting the font properties. I think we can raise it to Xcode forum.