# How to set font size to 16 in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I know how to change font size in Xcode [(REF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339706/how-to-increase-font-size-in-the-xcode-editor) and I am using Xcode 8.3.2. There are options like `11/12/13/14/18...` in the font window, but without 16. How can I make it?

**Edit:**

I tried to type `16` in the size text field directly, but won't help.

Comment: Select the number (not the on in the list), and write yourself "16"?

Comment: @Larme I write `16` for `Source Code Pro` and 'SF Mono', and close the preference window. It doesn't work.

Comment: @heLomaN Does dragging the slider in the font panel work? I noticed on Xcode 9 that typing a number in the font panel didn't change the font size, but dragging the slider allowed me to change the size to 15 and 16.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk Wow, it works just the same way in Xcode 8. Sincerely, big thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Larme mentioned, the font panel has a text field for you to enter the font size. If entering the font size doesn't change the font size, there's a slider in the font panel. Use the slider to change the font size to sizes that don't appear in the font panel list, such as 15 and 16 points.